# Flask-SQLAlchemy Как получить объекты связи один ко многим с нескольких "одних" сразу?

Tags: python, запрос, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Всем доброго дня, вопрос по Flask-SQLAlchemy на Python, казалось бы примитивный и должен быть распространённым, но чёткого ответа на него я не нашёл.

Есть условные объекты с некоторыми свойствами, возможно хранящимися через связи в других таблицах.
Есть условные снимки этих объектов в разные моменты времени с внешним ключом к объекту снимка (на один объект разное количество снимков).

Есть ли какой-то правильный и оптимальный путь получить сразу все снимки всех объектов соответствующих заданному условию?

```
class Object(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'objects'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    size = db.Column(db.Float)  # 0.8 < X < 12.3
    #...
    material_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('materials.id'))
    moments = db.relationship('Moment', backref='object', lazy='dynamic')


class Material(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'materials'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    color = db.Column(db.String)  # 'red', 'black', ..., None
    #...
    objects = db.relationship('Object', backref='material', lazy='dynamic')


class Moment(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'moments'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    #...
    object_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('objects.id'))
```

Вопрос попроще: Как наиболее просто и легко получить все снимки объектов, размер которых больше чем 4.5?

Вопрос сложнее: Как наиболее просто и легко получить все снимки объектов цвет которых 'black'?

Пока я нашёл только два решения и оба мне не очень нравятся:
1. Грубое решение в лоб, сначала сделать выборку интересующих объектов, а потом в цикле у каждого взять набор снимков и сложить в один массив, но это много кода и n + 1 запросов.
2. Способ хитрее, использовать переходы по обратным ссылкам на внешние ключи в условии основного запроса, что-то вроде:

```
Moment.query.filter(Moment.object.size > 4.5).all()
Moment.query.filter(Moment.object.material.color == 'black').all()
```

Кода не много, но это 2n запросов к базе (если я всё правильно понимаю), а в случае получения свойства из другой таблицы всё становится совсем плохо.

Умеет ли фласк и/или алхимия как-то элегантно решать эту задачу в один составной запрос? И если да, то можно узнать решение с примером и узнать что нужно прописывать в аргумент lazy отношения и обратной ссылки?

P.S. Так же буду признателен за сколько-нибудь современный источник, где можно почитать про практическое составление сложных запросов во фласк алхимии в доступных формулировках и с примерами (а то пока я видел только всякие квик старты с двумя примерами, либо уход в недры работы самой алхимии с запилом своих велосипедов).

Answer (score 1):

То, что вы хотите, весьма трудно реализовать связями (relationship), а возможно невозможно реализовать оптимально. Важно понимать, что relationship это не join'ы, хотя и могут джойнить, поэтому посмотрите в сторону джойнов, а не связей. Вот решение вашей задачи в 1 SQL запрос:

```
moments = Moment.query \
                .join(Object, (Object.id == Moment.object_id) & (Object.size > 4.5) ) \
                .join(Material, (Material.id == Object.material_id) & (Material.color == 'black')) \
                .all()

for moment in moments:
    print(f'moment id={moment.id}, object_id={moment.object_id}')
```

Этот SQLAlchemy-запрос сгенерирует следующий SQL-запрос:

```
SELECT moments.id AS moments_id, moments.object_id AS moments_object_id 
  FROM moments 
  JOIN objects 
    ON objects.id = moments.object_id
   AND objects.size > 4.5
  JOIN materials
    ON materials.id = objects.material_id
   AND materials.color = 'black'
```

Запрос возвращает коллекцию `Moment`, при желании Вы можете обернуть этот запрос как вам угодно и получить другие объекты с этими же условиями.

Ниже готовый шаблон для быстрого тестирования вместе с Flask-SQLAlchemy. После запуска его, запустите код представленные выше и вы получите тот результат, который описали в своём запросе.

```
from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///:memory:'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
# app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


import logging

logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


class Object(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'objects'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    size = db.Column(db.Float)  # 0.8 < X < 12.3
    material_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('materials.id'))


class Material(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'materials'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    color = db.Column(db.String)  # 'red', 'black', ..., None


class Moment(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'moments'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    object_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('objects.id'))


db.create_all()

mat = Material(id=1, color='black')
obj = Object(id=1, size=5.0, material_id=mat.id)
mom = Moment(id=1, object_id=obj.id)

db.session.add_all([mat, obj, mom])
db.session.commit()
```